# botones leer mas con funcionamiento errático

Tags: javascript

Tengo un div vacio al principio, place, donde inserto el div.full de la ultima noticia, al cargar la pagina.
Luego, tres divs "col",  cada uno con su div.sumary,div.full, y su boton , el span:more.
La idea es que , al click del boton, se borre el div hijo de place, el cargado de la ultima noticia, y lo reemplace con el div.full del div del boton clickeado.
y, segun el orden de click, lo agrega, y se ven dos noticias.
Algo me falla con el btnmas[i], que probe fuera de la instruccion, pero no funciona, tampoco.
Alguna idea?

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="place">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class"col">
            <div class="sumary">
                sumary1
                <span class"more"></span>
            </div>
        <div class"full">
            full1
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class"col">
            <div class="sumary">
                sumary2
                <span class"more">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="full">
                full2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class"col">
            <div class="sumary">
                sumary3
                <span class"more">
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="full">
                full3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
let todo = document.getElementsByClassName('full');
let btnmas = document.getElementsByClassName ("more");
let place = document.getElementById ("showlast");
let ultima = document.getElementsByClassName('full')[0];
place.appendChild (ultima);




for (let i = 0; i < btnmas.length; i++) {
  btnmas[i].innerHTML = "Leer más...";
  btnmas[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction );


function myFunction() {
  var x = todo[+i];
  var z = place.childNodes[0];
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    place.removeChild (place.childNodes[0]);
    x.style.display = 'block';
    place.appendChild(x);
  } else {
    
    x.style.display = 'none';
    place.removeChild;
  }

}
´´´
```

Comment: Para poder reproducir el problema en la pregunta misma, podés crear un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cosas que veo que estan mal en tu codigo:

1. Primero de todo las clases de elementos HTML: En tu código HTML, no están correctamente asignadas. Deberías usar class= en lugar de class". Por ejemplo,  en lugar de <div class"col">.
2. Referencia a elementos inexistentes: Estás intentando obtener un elemento con el id “showlast” que no existe en tu HTML. Deberías cambiar let place = document.getElementById ("showlast"); por let place = document.getElementById ("place");.
3. Ámbito de la variable i: En tu función myFunction, estás utilizando la variable i que está fuera del ámbito de la función. Esto podría causar problemas. Una solución sería pasar i como un argumento a myFunction.
4. Eliminación de elementos: En la línea place.removeChild;, parece que te has olvidado de pasar el nodo que quieres eliminar como argumento.

Prueba esto haber si te soluciona el problema:

```
let btnmas = document.getElementsByClassName("more");
let place = document.getElementById("place");
let ultima = document.getElementsByClassName('full')[0];
place.appendChild(ultima);

for (let i = 0; i < btnmas.length; i++) {
  btnmas[i].innerHTML = "Leer más...";
  btnmas[i].addEventListener('click', function() { myFunction(i); });
}

function myFunction(i) {
  var x = todo[i];
  var z = place.childNodes[0];
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    place.removeChild(place.childNodes[0]);
    x.style.display = 'block';
    place.appendChild(x);
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
    place.removeChild(place.childNodes[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Mi mayor problema era con el ambito de la variable i, que no sabia como sacarla para usarla luego.

Comment: @pablofernandez Si te he resuelto la duda por favor bota a favor de la respuesta y márcala como resuelta! Muchas gracias!